# State of the database when mixing HQL with native SQL in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

In my database code I use some Hibernate native SQL queries (inserts, deletion, updates). I understand that when I use HQL and the cache is on than the state of the DB is stable whenever I call the DB with the HQL. However, I wonder what happens if I use native SQL queries, e.g. I insert some data (but do not commit it) and than I try to fetch some data with a HQL query. Will I get the inserted data too?

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I would say, that it depends on  underlying database  and transactions setting.   But even HQL is translated to native SQL  and executed.  As long as you stay in same transaction,   you will be able to load changes made with native SQL via HQL.    But keep in mind, that HQL queries interat with caches, proxies and other hibernate stuff -  there could be some weird issues, because natiev SQL completely bypasses this ( this is purpose of native queries - fast lane around all the hibernate stuff )

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Konstantin Pribluda's answer I can say that in the reverse situation : adding data through Hibernate(even with session.save()) and then fetching data with native SQL resulted in the native SQL-query not fetching the added data.

So when using different types of query's in the DAO, I always flush the session first before I use a native SQL query... Never know which method's get mixed in the Service layer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you will get it because all of your DAO queries will executed one by one whether its HQL or SQL. So if insert query is first in order then you will get inserted records.